# How to get TextInput current cursor position in React Native

Tags: react-native, tags, textinput, react-native-textinput

Is there any way to get the cursor position of textinput in react native? What I want to achieve is that I have a textinput and on typing ' # ' on it, it will show up the list of options above the cursor's current position.

Similar to this image

[image]

Comment: See https://medium.com/@p9alisand/how-to-get-textinput-cursor-position-in-react-native-0-49-1845aee40e9b

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`onSelectionChange`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onselectionchange) for this:

```
<Input
  ...
  onSelectionChange={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.selection)}
/>
```